# ChucK - Using a class in another file

Tags: class, public, chuck

I am programming in ChucK programming language. I want to use a class declared in another file.

I have declared a public class called `Foo` in a file called `foo.ck`. Then I have added the file `foo.ck` in another file and tried to use the class. I have got this error:

```
[using_foo.ck]:line(2): undefined type 'Foo'...
[using_foo.ck]:line(2): ... in declaration ...
```

The file with the class (`foo.ck`):

```
public class Foo {}
Foo foo;
```

The file trying to use `Foo` (`using_foo.ck`):

```
Machine.add("foo.ck");
Foo foo;
```

The file `foo.ck` with the class `Foo` works if I run it standalone, but I cannot use the class from another file.

Chuck version:

```
chuck version: 1.5.0.0 (chai)
   linux (pulse) : 64-bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The class must be visible at *compile time*. When ChucK tries to compile `using_foo.ck`, it has not already run `foo.ck`. So it does not know the class `Foo`. The class is not visible. The function `Machine.add` is only run at *execution time*. In this case, it will not be run at all, because this script will not compile because the class `Foo` is not visible at compile time.

The solution is to run the file with the class (`foo.ck`) *before* the file using the class (`using_foo.ck`). There are two ways of doing it. In both ways, the line that is loading `foo.ck` (`Machine.add("foo.ck");`) must be removed, otherwise the file `foo.ck` will be loaded twice.

First way: run ChucK passing both files as arguments. The file with the class definition must come before the file using the class:

```
$ chuck foo.ck using_foo.ck
```

Second way: use a third file that adds both files. The file with the class definition must be added before the file using the class. Say the third file is called `init.ck`. Its code should be:

```
Machine.add("foo.ck");
Machine.add("using_foo.ck");
```

Then the command is:

```
$ chuck init.ck
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

In ChucK, to make one file aware of a class in another file, you should "spork" the file containing the class definition and ensure the order of code execution. Here's how you can fix it:

1. Make sure `foo.ck` only contains the class definition:

```
public class Foo {}
```

2. In your main file (using_foo.ck):

```
spork ~ Machine.add("foo.ck");
<<< now >>> => now + 10::ms;  // small delay to ensure Foo is loaded
Foo foo;
```

The delay (`<<< now >>> => now + 10::ms;`) ensures that the `Foo` class is properly loaded before you try to instantiate it in the main file. Adjust the delay as needed depending on your program's complexity.